# How can i save current-dateTime() in xml element using xquery?

Tags: xml, datetime, xpath, xquery, xforms

I need to find out how to save the xpath `current-dateTime()` output to a XML element.

The content username and password is get through an XForm. When the form is submitted the `action` attribute calls a .xquery file to process the form and stores it in the database. The .xquery file looks like this:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html indent=yes";

 (: Logs into the database :)
 let $login:=xmldb:login('/db/apps/example','foo','bar')

 (: Gets the data from the form :)
 let $newUser:=request:get-data()

 (: Names the file to be created :)
 let $file:=concat('user_',$newUser/user/username/text(),'.xml')

 (: Stores the file in the database :)
 let $store:= xmldb:store('/db/apps/example/users',$file,$newUser)

 return
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SUCCESS!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>The user: </b> {$newUser/user/usernamename/text()} <b> has been added!</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok, this runs just fine and creates a nice XML file just like I want that has this structure:

```
<user>
   <username>stewie_griffin</username>
   <password>kill_louis</password>
   <date_created/>
</user>
```

**But what if I want to save the current date and time in the `/user/date_created` element? I don't know how to do it and I've been looking almost three days for examples and searching and I can't find anything useful...**

Why can't I just do something like this in the .xquery file?

```
$newUser/user/date_created:=current-dateTime()
```

and have the xml file saved like this?

```
<user>
   <username>stewie_griffin</username>
   <password>kill_louis</password>
   <date_created>2006-04-10T13:40:23.83</date_created>
</user>
```

Could some help me to save the output of the `current-dateTime()` function?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't do something like `$newUser/user/date_created:=current-dateTime()` is that in XQuery, as in most functional languages, data are immutable.

You can create a new document with the information you want:

```
let $doc := <user>{
              $newUser//user/(* except date_created),
              <date_created>{current-dateTime()}</date_created>
            }</user>
```

and then later pass $doc, not $newUser, to the store() function.

I expect you could also use the XQuery Update Facility, but beware of using updates as if it were assignment in a conventional imperative language.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Took me some serious work-around since my xml structure is way more complex than that! But worked like a charm. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

*@adamretter stated in the comments that eXist DB only supports a subset of XQuery Update and misses transformation statements. I'll keep this answer as reference for other visitors using different database systems.*

In addition to C. M. Sperberg-McQueen's answer, the [XQuery Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-transform) version, here using a transformation statement. The relevant two lines are the ones with `copy` and `modify`.

```
(: This would be your get-data call :)
let $newUser :=
    <user>
       <username>stewie_griffin</username>
       <password>kill_louis</password>
       <date_created/>
    </user>
return
  (: Copy to the same name, we don't need the old variable value any more. :)
  (: Be aware we're not changing the variable, but cover it with a new one. :)
  copy $newUser := $newUser
  (: Change the date_created value with the current timestamp :)
  modify replace value of node $newUser/date_created with current-dateTime()
  return $newUser
```

`copy`/`modify` are allow you to use updating statements. Regarding why you can't use `let` for this, I'm not completely sure: my guess would be either not wanting to change the original language too much from an extension, just making it easier for the implementors or having a more descriptive language, clearly indicating what is performed.

Comment: Hi @Jens Erat, could you explain `copy` in your example - I see it is implemented in BaseX and Zorba, but somehow I don't see it in the recommendation. What would be the difference from using `let` here?

Comment: This is an [XQuery Update transformation statement](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-transform). I'll also add the link to the answer.

Comment: It may look different as the XQuery in the question was for eXist-db and eXist-db only implements an early draft of the XQuery Update spec and not the recommended spec, so there are some syntactical differences.